# Multiple xml data output from the server on socket php

Tags: php, xml, sockets, networking, server

I'm using php socket programming to connect to this server( An Alarm Processing Unit Device) so as to receive an XML file data which i wanna process in other to display video live stream from a cameras on the same network. I was able to use php socket to connect to it and retrieve the information but the information comes in multiple, i have the same xml data always repeating it self in four places.

This is always the outcome i get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR APU</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Hyperzone</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:36:24.091</UpdateTime> </Status> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H1.Z1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:36:24.091</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H1.Z2</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:36:24.091</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H2</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Hyperzone</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:36:24.091</UpdateTime> </Status> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification>

<DeviceName>tes1.H2.Z3</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:36:24.091</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR APU</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Hyperzone</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:36:44.103</UpdateTime> </Status> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H1.Z1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:36:44.103</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H1.Z2</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:36:44.103</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H2</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Hyperzone</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:36:44.103</UpdateTime> </Status> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification>

<DeviceName>tes1.H2.Z3</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:36:44.103</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR APU</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Hyperzone</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:37:04.118</UpdateTime> </Status> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H1.Z1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:37:04.118</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H1.Z2</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:37:04.118</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H2</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Hyperzone</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:37:04.118</UpdateTime> </Status> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification>

<DeviceName>tes1.H2.Z3</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:37:04.118</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR APU</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Hyperzone</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:37:24.136</UpdateTime> </Status> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H1.Z1</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:37:24.136</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H1.Z2</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Zone</DeviceType> </DeviceIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:37:24.136</UpdateTime> </Status> </DeviceStatusReport> </PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformStatusReport> <PlatformIdentification> <DeviceName>tes1.H2</DeviceName> <DeviceCategory>Sensor</DeviceCategory> <DeviceType>SPIDR Hyperzone</DeviceType> </PlatformIdentification> <Status> <DeviceState>Secure</DeviceState> <CommunicationState>OK</CommunicationState> <UpdateTime Zone="GMT">2017-07-12T21:37:24.136</UpdateTime> </Status> <DeviceStatusReport> <DeviceIdentification>
```

This is code i have to bring about the otput

```
   <?php
//timeout limit
set_time_limit(0);

//Creating Socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "<br />";
} else {
    echo "OK.<br />";
}

echo "Attempting to connect to the socket'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, '192.168.43.50', 10001);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.<br />Reason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "<br />";
} else {
    echo "OK.<br />";
}
$in = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r<br />";
$in .= "Host: 192.168.43.50\r<br />";
$in .= "Content-Type: application/xml; encoding=UTF-8\r\n";
$in .= "Accept: application/xml\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r<br />\r<br />";
$out = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>';
$out= '';

echo "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
echo "OK.<br />";

echo "Reading response:<br /><br />";
while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
    echo htmlspecialchars ($out)."<br /><br />";
}

echo "Closing socket...";
socket_close($socket);
echo "OK.<br /><br />";

?>
```

and if i decided to remove the while loop on the result output 
it displays just a single line of the information required and stops connection, but i dont want that because the system is supposed to be a real time monitoring solution which means i must be connected to the server all times or get the server's return everytime it posts to the network

Please what can i do about this,,?
Thank you

Comment: You need to split messages before parsing using the xml identification <xml....  TCP datagrams are variable size and messages can be split and recombined by servers and routers with max size of ~1500 bytes.  You do not need to close and open socket.  Just make sure you process one complete xml feed at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this kind of use with PHP. But i think your problem might come from "socket_read" which i guess has an unexpected behaviour.

You may want to check comments on the official doc page, someone is having the same kind of trouble with a while loop and socket_read : http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php

Also you might be interested in socket_recv : http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php

As you want to be permanently connected to the server, and assuming it is well configured (no timeout, etc), i think would not close the socket connexion.

Hope this helped.

Comment: HI NoxWorld, Thanks for the concern... I did check the comment on the official page but isn't what i wanted and socket_recv is also giving me multiple output .